# Is singular Cauchy operator bounded in Morrey spaces?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, operator-theory

The singular Cauchy operator is defined by
$$S_\Gamma :f \to \int_\Gamma \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z} d\xi , z\in \Gamma.$$
Is this operator bounded in Morrey spaces and weighted Morrey spaces? i.e.
is there a constant $c$ such for any $f$ belongs to Morrey space the following inequality is true
$$|| S_\Gamma f|| < c ||f\|$$